# Async Await Problems with node-canvas loadImage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, async-await

I can't get an async await function get to work in node js. I use the [node canvas repository](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#loadimage) to load a local image. When trying to access the returned value, it is still a Promise, even if I await it. How can I fix the code?

```
   async function loadMyLocalImage() {
      const img = await loadImage("pathToMyImage/img.jpg"); // loadImage is a function from node canvas package https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#loadimage      
      return img;
    }

    let localImage = loadMyLocalImage();
    console.log(localImage); // returns: Promise { <pending> }

    const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
    const ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(localImage, 0, 0);
```

This code throws the error:

```
ctx.drawImage(localImage, 0, 0);
     ^

TypeError: Image or Canvas expected
```

Because `localImage` is still a Promise at this point.

How can I wait for my Promise to resolve in this code snippet, before executing the next functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a promise, not the actual value you need. And so your function is not really adding anything to what `loadImage` already does: it returns a promise.

So, .. move your output logic, and any other code that needs the promised value, inside your function, right after `await`:

```
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
const ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d");

async function loadAndProcessMyLocalImage() {
  const localImage = await loadImage("pathToMyImage/img.jpg");      
  console.log(localImage);
  ctx.drawImage(localImage, 0, 0); 
}

loadAndProcessMyLocalImage();
```

Answer (score 2):

loadMyLocalImage is a function that returns a promise

```
async function loadMyLocalImage() {
    const img = await loadImage("pathToMyImage/img.jpg");       
    console.log(img);
    const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(localImage, 0, 0); 
}

loadMyLocalImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, You need to use promise and inside that **.then** and **.catch** and the response that you will get after **.then** or **.catch** that will be your real your value. either *success* after using **.then** or *error* after using **.catch** .
Always return promise while using async await . and if you have more than one request for await then use promise.all otherwise simply return promise .